# Apache MINA SSHD session echoes characters twice when using ProcessShellFactory, control characters don't work

Tags: echo, tty, sshd, apache-mina, apache-sshd

I'm running OpenJDK 14 on macOS 10.15.7. I'm doing some proof-of-concept code establishing an SSH server with Apache Mina SSHD and then connecting to it. Here's what I have:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.sshd.common.cipher.BuiltinCiphers;
import org.apache.sshd.common.util.logging.AbstractLoggingBean;
import org.apache.sshd.server.ServerBuilder;
import org.apache.sshd.server.SshServer;
import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.AsyncAuthException;
import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.password.PasswordAuthenticator;
import org.apache.sshd.server.auth.password.PasswordChangeRequiredException;
import org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession;
import org.apache.sshd.server.shell.InteractiveProcessShellFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.shell.ProcessShellFactory;

public class FunctionalTest
{
    private static class TestAuthenticator
        extends AbstractLoggingBean
        implements PasswordAuthenticator
    {
        @Override
        public boolean authenticate(String username, String password, ServerSession session)
            throws PasswordChangeRequiredException, AsyncAuthException
        {
            if ("test".equals(username) && "foobar".equals(password))
            {
                this.log.info("authenticate({}[{}]: accepted", username, session);
                return true;
            }

            this.log.warn("authenticate({}[{}]: rejected", username, session);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException
    {
        SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setHost("0.0.0.0");
        sshd.setPort(1022);
        sshd.setShellFactory(InteractiveProcessShellFactory.INSTANCE);
        sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new TestAuthenticator());
        sshd.setCipherFactories(Arrays.asList(BuiltinCiphers.aes256ctr, BuiltinCiphers.aes192ctr));
        sshd.setKeyExchangeFactories(ServerBuilder.setUpDefaultKeyExchanges(false));
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(Paths.get("key.ser")));
        sshd.start();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(3_600_000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Caught interrupt ... stopping server.");
            sshd.stop(true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I start this, I can `ssh -p 1022 test@localhost` with the password `foobar` and it works. After successful authentication, I first see this:

```
sh: no job control in this shell
```

Then at the prompt, characters I type (including newlines) are echoed twice instead of once, resulting in everything being dduupplliiccaatteedd:

```
williamsn:mina-test williamsn$ llss  --aall

total 24
... (list of files)
williamsn:mina-test williamsn$ eecchhoo  hheelllloo
hello

williamsn:mina-test williamsn$
```

Additionally, if I run an interactive command like `top`, it doesn't recognize my inputs, and control characters don't work. `ttoopp` starts (though its output is ugly and additive instead of replacing the screen), but if I type `q` to exit (`q` is not echoed twice in this case), `top` does not exit in response to the `q`. It just keeps going. `ctrl+c` also does not work—`top` just keeps going. The only way to exit top is to kill my `ssh` process or shut down the MINA server.

I feel like I must be doing something terribly wrong here. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The "no job control" message indicates that the spawned shell Is not in a full interactive mode, and the double letters show that you have a mismatch between local and remote character echo.
I can only assume that the default shell on mac-os (/usr/bin/sh ) is not a bash implementation like it is on Linux. Try changing the shell factory to new ProcessShellFactory("/usr/bin/bash","-i")

Sorry I don't have a mac to try this out.

Paul

Comment: Thanks, Paul! I actually tried Bash first, before trying `sh`, with the exact same behavior, but just different wording: I used `sshd.setShellFactory(new ProcessShellFactory("bash", "/usr/local/bin/bash", "-i"));` (note that the `ProcessShellFactory` documentation is out of date and that new, first argument is required now), and output like in the following comment:

Comment: Password authentication [\n]
Password: [\n]
bash: cannot set terminal process group (67423): Inappropriate ioctl for device [\n]
bash: no job control in this shell [\n]
bash-5.0$

Comment: having exactly same issue. any update?  @Nick. tried also on centos, same.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. And nobody ever replies on the mailing list, so I gave up.